# Recommended resources for starter in quantum computing and its eventual applications on machine learning

Tags: resource-request, machine-learning, quantum-enhanced-machine-learning

A growing interest in Quantum Computing -particularly in its eventual applications on Machine Learning- has taken over me and I would like to follow that path. I have strong Maths (Calculus, Multivariate Calculus, Linear Algebra, Math. Analysis, etc) and Probability foundations but my knowledge in Physics is rather poor.

I also have some knowledge in common Machine Learning.

What subjects should I study and -if possible- what books per subject could I try?

I will probably do this on my own but I don't mind taking rigourous books if it's needed.

Thanks a lot, I know the answer to my question is a large one and I appreciate the effort it will take to approach it.

Comment: Check out the PennyLane QML tutorials. https://pennylane.ai/qml/

Comment: Nielson and Chuang is the gold standard for beginner/intermediate QC and QML imo